# Accessing IIS website over ad hoc wireless network

Tags: iis-7, adhoc-network

I have our website setup on a Windows 7 box running IIS for a demo in a building with no access to the Internet. The plan is that the demo box will have a wireless adhoc network setup on it and several laptops will connect to that network and show the website.

However, in my tests I can setup and connect to the adhoc network fine. The machines can ping each other, but I can't view the website.

I just get:
The connection has timed out
The server at 192.168.1.71 is taking too long to respond.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

The firewall was on, but it's now off on both machines and I'm still getting the same result. Here is my output from a ping followed by a telnet session:

```
Ping statistics for 169.254.33.28:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 3ms, Average = 1ms

C:\Users\Richard>telnet 169.254.33.28 80
Connecting To 169.254.33.28...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80:
 Connect failed
```

I always get a new IP address when I set up the network, but you can see that the ping works, but we're getting nothing on port 80. On the host machine I can browse to that IP address fine.

**UPDATE UPDATE**

I failed to notice that you can turn the firewall on and off for different profiles and I'd only turned it off for the domain profile. Turning it off completely fixed the problem, which meant the firewall was the problem.

So, thankyou @user48838 for pointing me in the right direction.

So I've turned the firewall back on and enabled the incoming rule for HTTP traffic, which I probably should have done first rather than trying to take the short cut of turning off the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the firewall settings on the system running the web server? What displays when one of the remote systems telnet to the web server over port 80?

Comment: The firewall was on, which was really stupid of me. But even after turning it off I don't seem to be any closer. I've updated my question to answer your telnet question.

Comment: Sorry. I hadn't turned the firewall off. I failed to notice that there were 3 seperate profiles and I'd only turned it off for the domain profile. I turned it off for all and it was fine. I've now enabled the inbound rule for HTTP traffic and all is well.

Comment: Sounds like 2008R2. It's firewall settings seem a little more convoluted.